# GAE Datastore query

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore

I'm trying to list all the Users that are entered into my datastore in my test GAE app and print out the usernames of each one. However, when I run the code below I get an error saying

> self.query = User.all()
>   AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'all'

I thought that `self.query = User.all()` would return all the users in my database?

My code is below.
Thanks in advance!

PS. I know my userfinder form is asking for a username and doing nothing with it, but filtering is a task for later - I just want to make sure I've got the basic query going first.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

import webapp2
import uuid

class User(ndb.Model):
    db_UID = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = True)
    db_username = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = True)
    db_password = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = True)
    db_email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = True)
    db_resetID = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = True)


class UsersPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    self.response.write('<html><body><h1>User Info Page</h1>')
    self.response.write("""
        <form method = "post">
        Username: <input type = "textarea" name = "user_username"></input><br>
        Password: <input type = "textarea" name = "user_password"></input><br>
        Email address: <input type = "textarea" name = "user_email"></input><br>
        <input type = "submit"></input>
        </form>""")
    self.response.write('</body></html>')

def post(self):
    UNIQUE_ID_STRING = str(uuid.uuid1())
    self.user = User(db_UID = UNIQUE_ID_STRING ,
        db_username = self.request.get('user_username'), 
        db_password = self.request.get('user_password'),
        db_email = self.request.get('user_email'))
    self.user.put()
    self.redirect('/user')



class UserFinder(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.write('<html><body><h1>Search username</h1>')
    self.response.write("""
        <form method = "post">
        Username: <input type = "textarea" name = "user_username"></input><br>
        <input type = "submit"></input>
        </form>""")
    self.response.write('</body></html>')

def post(self):
    self.query = User.all()
    self.response.write('<html><body><h1>Search username</h1>')

    for self.user in self.query:
        self.response.write('<p>%s</p>' % self.User.db_username)

    self.response.write('</body></html>')


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/user', UsersPage),
('/userfinder', UserFinder),
], debug = True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the basic 'db' version, NDB Models don't use `all()` for querying, they use `query()`, so

```
self.query = User.query()
```

The [NDB docs on queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries) might be useful.

As an aside, using `self` as much as you are is a little unusual; aside from the calls to `self.response.write` and to `self.redirect`, just using local variables will be a lot less confusing (good if you have to post more questions!), and will save you typing.
So your post method would become:

```
query = User.all()
self.response.write('<html><body><h1>Search username</h1>')

for user in query:
  self.response.write('<p>%s</p>' % user.db_username)

self.response.write('</body></html>')
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Greg for such a clear and useful answer! I used a tutorial to write the queries and they used self in their code so I took it from that as I assumed it was necessary. I will take them out.

I have modified my post method to the code below but I'm now getting an error saying that 

query = User.query()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'User' referenced before assignment.

I thought the query was acting on the User class?

My code is now:

Comment: def post(self):
        query = User.query()
        self.response.write('<html><body><h1>Search username</h1>')

        for User in query:
        self.response.write('<p>%s</p>' % User.db_username)

        self.response.write('</body></html>')

Comment: Try renaming your variable to 'user' - it's probably clashing with the User class.

Comment: For some reason I can't format this post as code so I've posted a link to a screenshot of it to make it clearer

http://snag.gy/zZGVB.jpg

Comment: Tried it with user, user1 and User and it's giving the same error each time. It doesn't like the line which says query = User.query() apparently